# Reading an LDR array with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ldr, charlieplexing

I am trying to repurpose a replica [GPO 746](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPO_telephones#Type_746) using a Raspberry Pi, however the rotary mechanism is rather different to that in an original 746. The circuit has 12 LDRs arranged in an array (3 columns, 4 rows), a shutter attached to the dial, and an LED above the shutter. The shutter is arranged so that when the dial is rotated, a single LDR is illuminated by the LED. The finger stop incorporates a microswitch which powers the LED. I've included a rough circuit diagram below.

The row and column wires were previously connected to an [HM9102D](http://www.datasheet-pdf.info/entry/HM9102D), however I cannot reliably replicate the setup using a Raspberry Pi. Reading the GPIO pins via multiplexing seems to have inputs triggered at random, even when the LED is off.

How can I reliably read the inputs from the dial?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq2AMt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you define Req of LDR with Light ON/OFF? and thus make window comparators reliable for logic level detection? Can you ensure wiring does not pickup noise using twisted pair AWG 30 Magnet wire? Can you detect source/destination of noise current loop?  Do you have noise filters for FL light flicker or DC ripple??

Comment: The Charlieplexing style requires unidirectional elements of the matrix. LDR is bidirectional.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Pretty much no to all of that...

Comment: Then you know what you need to learn  Generally Vishay/Sharp/Infineon PD's are less sensitive (hi Z) than LDRs, but far more accurate. So start with IR or Red  LED and black or clear PD (respectively) and measure I=V/R with light on /off with close distance using narrowest angle LED.

Comment: @utu2012 Sorry, got charlieplexing and multiplexing mixed up. I've corrected the post now.

Comment: Learn optical design , then use of PD's and LED's with gap Loss (inverse squared) then mW(optical)/mA(electrical) . PD is ~0.4 A/W

Comment: @CyberJacob, the multiplexing requires unidirectional elements of the matrix too.

Comment: It's not a restriction, it could be a diode switch, PD, LDR, Cap, R anything in a matrix Row/column scanner as long as V and SNR is in range.

Comment: @CyberJacob, One solution is to put a Schottky diode in series with every photoresistor [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29076/unstable-readings-in-photoresistor-matrix-with-arduino-ok-with-ohmmeter-what)

Comment: @utu2012 How was the HM9102D reading it?

Comment: @CyberJacob, Something like this [page 2-34,Рin description tab,Description](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/103711/UMC/UM91260.html)

Comment: @utu2012 not sure if that link is going to the right place?

Comment: @CyberJacob, [direct link to pdf](http://pdf.dzsc.com/UM9/UM91260.pdf)

Comment: @utu2012 sorry, I'm not seeing how that would help. Could you explain in a little more detail? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57206/discussion-between-utu2012-and-cyberjacob).